# Toolbox in visual studio not working after installing DevExpress

Tags: visual-studio-2015, devexpress, toolbox

My toolbox in visual studio 2015 does not show anything. It just says "There are no usable controls in this group". This took place after I installed DevExpress v16.2., but I worked with the toolbox for a while after installing.It just stopped all of sudden. How do I get the toolbox back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please use our **ToolboxAnalizer** tool from the [How to resolve
>   issues with Toolbox items](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/KA18574.aspx) KB article. It will try to repair the
>   toolbox. If it doesn't succeed, it will collect the required log files
>   and ask you to send them to us. Do this. We will research them. In
>   addition, provide us with the installation log file, which you can
>   locate in the C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 15.1\Components folder
>   to check if there were no errors during installation.

**References:**
[How to resolve issues with Toolbox items](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18574)